# Consultar dados do usuário logado Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, active-directory

Em minha aplicação utilizo o `authentication mode="Windows"`  como forma de autenticação.

Dessa forma, eu consigo saber o nome do usuário, referente ao campo no AD e o domínio do mesmo utilizando `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, ex: `DOMAIN\username`.
Gostaria de saber, se consigo recuperar as outras informações do usuário, como e-mail, descrição, etc.

Utilizando o [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider&oq=ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) eu tenho acesso aos outros campos, como  `userprincipalname, samaccountname, mail, etc`.
Gostaria de saber se utilizando o `authentication mode="Windows"`  eu consego retornar esses dados.
Se não, consigo retornar algum outro dado além do `authentication mode="Windows"` ?

Comment: @Marconi eu já verifiquei isso, mas não encontrei. Eu estou utilizando o Identity, com authentication mode="windows". Com isso, não estou conseguindo acessar essas propriedades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escrevi um `Helper` (uma classe estática com métodos estáticos) com um método que localiza os usuários de um domínio com as respectivas informações e outro que detalha um usuário em específico:

```
using MeuProjeto.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class ActiveDirectoryHelper
    {
        public static ActiveDirectoryUserViewModel GetADUser(String search)
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "meudominiodoad"))
            {
                var result = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, search);

                var groups = result.GetGroups().ToList();

                return new ActiveDirectoryUserViewModel
                {
                    DisplayName = result.DisplayName,
                    Email = result.EmailAddress,
                    Mapped = true,
                    UserName = result.UserPrincipalName,
                    Groups = result.GetGroups()
                };
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ActiveDirectoryUserViewModel> GetADUsers()
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "meudominiodoad"))
            {
                using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                {
                    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                        yield return new ActiveDirectoryUserViewModel
                        {
                            DisplayName = (de.Properties["displayName"].Value ?? de.Properties["name"].Value).ToString(),
                            UserName = de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString()
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui estão as [`Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.propertycollection(v=vs.110).aspx) de [`DirectoryEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que você pode usar.